# OpenLayers call ArcGIS WFS: no feature returned

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, wfs, openlayers-2

I spent a long time looking for an example using OpenLayers to call ArcGIS WFS, however, almost none is found... currently the code I wrote is based on the example of GeoServer, however, no feature is returned...

```js
new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("ArcGIS WFS layer", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        srsName: "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:26912",
            url: "http://XXXX/Geodatabase_SDE/geodataserver/WFSServer?request=getFeature",
        featureType: "TEST_SAMPLE",
        featureNS: "http://XXXX/Geodatabase_SDE/geodataserver/WFSServer",
        geometryName: "Shape"
    })
});
```

I am wondering if it's doable in OpenLayers?

**UPDATE**
***Request XML:***

```xml
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <wfs:Query srsName="EPSG:26912" typeName="feature:TEST_SAMPLE" xmlns:feature="http://XXXX/Geodatabase_SDE/geodataserver/WFSServer">
    <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <ogc:BBOX>
        <ogc:PropertyName>
          Shape
        </ogc:PropertyName>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:26912" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <gml:lowerCorner>
            447517.58546862 4364229.0103902
          </gml:lowerCorner>
          <gml:upperCorner>
            455008.41453138 4384331.9496098
          </gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </ogc:BBOX>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

***Response XML:***

```xml
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:Geodatabase_SDE="http://XXXXX/Geodatabase_SDE/GeoDataServer/WFSServer" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://XXXXX/Geodatabase_SDE/GeoDataServer/WFSServer http://XXXXX/Geodatabase_SDE/geodataserver/WFSServer?request=DescribeFeatureType%26version=1.1.0%26typename=TEST_SAMPLE http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:26912">
      <gml:lowerCorner>
        NaN NaN
      </gml:lowerCorner>
      <gml:upperCorner>
        NaN NaN
      </gml:upperCorner>
    </gml:Envelope>
  </gml:boundedBy>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Comment: Do you have a public facing URL we can test on?

Comment: i don't have public accessible WFS. i was looking for one in order to test, but didn't find anything online...

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't find a public ArcGIS WFS service either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the response from the server (the XML that is returned) - does it show any warnings?

Also try setting your srsName to a simpler form such as:

```
srsName: "EPSG:26912"
```

I've been through the same (unpleasant) process of configuring OpenLayers and MapServer WFS. There are details at http://geographika.co.uk/mapserver-openlayers-and-the-wfs-maze

The most confusing piece was that even if the XML request included the SRS, I also had to pass it as a parameter in the URL:

```
http://localhost/mapserver/?map=C:/PathToMapFile/mymap.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&srsName=EPSG:900913
```

This may or may not apply to all WFS servers - I'd be interested to know if it is also the case with ArcGIS.

A few other things to check are:

- is the projection set up on the ArcGIS Server
- if you run a profiler on your database, what SQL is running - and are the correct bounding boxes being used?
- what projection is your OpenLayers basemap in? Do you have proj4js added into the web page?

The request looks good, but clearly the repsonse and the NaN (not a number) show something is wrong.

Comment: @Simon Can you also post the request XML - this should include the bounds sent to the server.

Comment: thanks very much for advice. since it's not me setting up the arcgis server, it may take some time to figure out the projection issue on server...and i assume it's very possible due to that.. i just added VERSION&srsName to URL, not succeed.